# How to scroll in ScrollPane with mouse?

Tags: javafx

Is it possible to move  vertically and horizontally without using scrollbar in `ScrollPane` i want to scroll when left mouse button pressed and mouse moved to right, left, top and down . Should i add listener or something like that ?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just call

```
scrollPane.setPannable(true);
```

or, if you are using FXML

```
<ScrollPane pannable="true" ... >
```